# Running "docker exec" displays "bash-4.2" in "Shell command prompt"

Tags: linux, docker, shell, prompt

```bash
docker run -itd --restart always --network host --name test_db -h test_db -v share:/home/share -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --privileged mariadb_10.8 init
```

Running `docker exec -it test_db bash` displays `root@test_db` in the shell command prompt, but after someday `bash-4.2` appeared.
And there is no `ll` command and no `/root` folder

How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: I'd expect that MariaDB container to _only_ be running a database and nothing else.  There's no particular reason to try to run `bash` inside of it.  You should be able to interact with it using normal MariaDB/MySQL client libraries and command-line tools, without using `docker exec` and without trying to customize a debugging shell.

Comment: Sorry.. 
'mariadb_10.8' is not an image in docker hub.
I installed mariadb using Yum on 'centos:7' image.
And I commited to create a new image of 'mariadb_10.8'.
For this reason, root@localhost was displayed.
However, after some point, bash is displayed.